# Use DbContext to configure Identity in Program.cs in Blazor project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Another day, another struggle with understanding of ASP.NET core!

I want to configure some of the options in builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity from the database using the DB service added to the container.

Current Program.cs code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PTSBlazor.Services;
using PTSModels;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PTSConnection");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
});
    

// Identity configuration
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<PTSUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
}
).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

How do I go about using ApplicationDbContext to set the options.Password options (RequireUppercase, RequiredLength etc.) in the DefaultIdentity configuration?

I'm migrating from an older ASP.NET MVC Project where this was done in IdentityConfig.vb in the App_Start folder.

Comment: Does your ApplicationDbContext already inherit IdentityDbContext<PTUser> ?

Comment: Yes, the PTSUser class inherits IdentityUser

Comment: "How do I go about using ApplicationDbContext to set the options.Password options" I dont understand this question as in my eyes you already configure the password requirements

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. Where I'm setting the password parameters:

`options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;`

I want to pull the values from the database. So I have a method in my ApplicationDbContext that allows me to get settings; so I wan't to be able to do something like this:

options.Password.RequireUppercase = db.GetAppSetting("PWDREQUPPER");
options.Password.RequiredLength = db.GetAppSetting("PWDREQLENGTH");

Comment: this is not a good idea. put config in appsettings.json. or set it later, in a service. in both senario you have to restart app to activate new options

Comment: Our users generally don’t have access to the server but may occasionally need to make these sort of changes: hence the need for them to be in the database. How would I go about configuring a service to change these settings? Apologies for my lack of knowledge of .NET Core.